# Why Context.User.Identity.Name is empty from Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, signalr

I can't figure out why when I try to connect from Xamarin Context.User.Indetity.Name is empty. Is there anything special I need to do? I logged in to the server and the user has a connection stablished. After that I use the following code:

```
var Connection = new HubConnection(Url);
_hub = Connection.CreateHubProxy(hubName);
_hub.On(srvEvent, onData);

await Connection.Start();
```

But I never get the username. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code for the server:

```
var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
Connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
return base.OnConnected();
```

It works when it comes from the web app, not from the xamarin app.

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of authentication are you using for signalr?

Comment: @JGEstevez sorry, I'm new to SignalR, is there such a thing? I thought it was just like the web part. I thought it'd share the context.

Comment: Yes, you need to decorate your hub or one of your hub function with the authorize attribute, then in the startup class you need to configure the authentication the same way you do it for a web api or an mvc project

Comment: in my case, I'm using signalr for a chat that will be used in a website and android app and ios app, these apps also uses an api that is protected with an OAuth2 server so for my signalr I'm using the same Oauth2 server  for authentication, but I need to pass the access token to signalr so the validation can works, I have a code that you can use as a guide, let me know if you want it

Comment: @JGEstevez yes, please. I'm gonna check and see if the authorize attribute fixes this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code I was telling you about.

I'm using an external OAuth2 server for authentication, so I must pass the access token to SignalR somehow, because SignalR uses web sockets for the messages back and forth I can't pass the access token in the header because this is not supported by web sockets.

I'm passing that access token as a query string parameter this way (Javascript client)

```
$.connection.hub.qs = "access_token=" + mytoken;
```

Then on my SignalR I added a middleware that takes that query string and adds it to the header as an Authorization header using Bearer Token. This is done this way in my startup class

```
app.UseAuthQSTokenExtractor();
```

The code for the middleware is this one

```
namespace Owin
{
    public static class AuthorizationQSTokenExtractorExtension
    {
        public static void UseAuthQSTokenExtractor(this IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use<AuthorizationQsTokenExtractorMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}


namespace Chat.Middleware
    {
        public class AuthorizationQsTokenExtractorMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
        {

            public AuthorizationQsTokenExtractorMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
                : base(next)
            {

            }

            public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("signalr-auth-middleware");

                string bearerToken = context.Request.Query.Get("access_token");
                Debug.WriteLine("signar-bearer: " + bearerToken);
                if (bearerToken != null)
                {
                    TokenHelper.DecodeAndWrite(bearerToken);
                    string[] authorization = { "Bearer " + bearerToken };
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
                }

                await Next.Invoke(context);

            }
        }
```

My startup class then looks like this

```
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseAuthQSTokenExtractor();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
               new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:idserver"],
                   RequiredScopes = new[]
                   {
                            "chat-hub"
                   }
               });

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration ();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;            
            app.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

You can see in the code above where I tell SignalR to use the Oauth2 Server, that code is this one

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
               new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:idserver"],
                   RequiredScopes = new[]
                   {
                            "chat-hub"
                   }
               });
```

After all this is set up I have access to my Context.User.Identity.Name and if you want to get the others IdentityClaim you can do this

```
var identity = Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

Which I'm using that code above to get the subjectId (userid) like this

```
public static string[] GetIdentityClaimsIssSub(HubCallerContext Context)
        {
            var identity = Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;


            if (identity == null)
                return null;

            var issuerFromIdentity = identity.FindFirst("iss");
            var subFromIdentity = identity.FindFirst("sub");

            if (issuerFromIdentity == null || subFromIdentity == null)
                return null;

            return new string[] { issuerFromIdentity.Value, subFromIdentity.Value };
        }
```

I hope it helps